Module: how to include named module from Public folder?
I've created a module in my UE5 game, called MinimapSystem and structured it like this (this is inside my game's Source folder):
MinimapSystem
    ├───MinimapSystem.Build.cs
    ├───Private
    │   └───MinimapSubsystem.cpp
    └───Public
        └───MinimapSubsystem.h

Here's the contents of my MinimapSystem.Build.cs file:
using UnrealBuildTool;


public class MinimapSystem : ModuleRules
{
    public MinimapSystem(ReadOnlyTargetRules Target) : base(Target)
    {
        PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[]
        {
            "Core",
            "CoreUObject",
            "Engine",
            "UMG"
        });
    }
}

This imitates what I see in the core UE5 module structure, and when I include one of those modules, I don't need to specify the Public/ part of the path, i.e.
#include "GeometryCollection/GeometryCollectionActor.h"

So, in my game, I try the same thing with my module:
#include "MinimapSystem/MinimapSubsystem.h"

But this throws a fatal error when I try to compile:

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'MinimapSystem/MinimapSubsystem.h': No such file or directory

The only way to compile my game is if I specify the Public/ folder like this:
#include "MinimapSystem/Public/MinimapSubsystem.h"

I have added my module to MyGame.Build.cs like this:
        PublicDependencyModuleNames.AddRange(new string[]
        {
            "Core",
            "MinimapSystem",
        });

How do I include my module by its name from the Public folder?

I remember this public/private folders. I think when you are creating a class, you can create it without public/private folders (maybe there is a checkbox, which shouldn't be checked). Then, it will create .cpp and .h files outside (not in public/private folder).

It turns out that #include "MinimapSubsystem.h" works, but I'm still confused why I can't use #include MinimapSystem/MinimapSubsystem.h

The solution is to structure the module like this:
MinimapSystem
    ├───MinimapSystem.Build.cs
    ├───Private
    │   └───MinimapSubsystem
    │       └───MinimapSubsystem.cpp
    └───Public
        └───MinimapSubsystem
            └───MinimapSubsystem.h

This emulates the actual structure of i.e. the GeometryCollection module. Now, I can include my module like:
#include "MinimapSystem/MinimapSubsystem.h"

